# How shall I store growing collection of videos?

Tags: backup, storage

Little bit of background: I've been video content creator for few years and I'm storing/backuping videos I produced, "just in case". I don't store source files but only finished product and accompanying material. I repurposed older external drive with loose connector as a backup store and it's been working so far but I'm approaching its 1TB limit. What should I do now? Options as I see them are:

- Buy another drive and use that one when first one is full. Should I get external or internal one?
- Subscribe to some online backup service. I'm yet to find one that would offer just to save files without all cloud/sync stuff.
- Any other option?

I would appreciate any and all feedback. Files we are talking about will be accessed very rarely if ever, if that's important.

Comment: I use Raid 1 enclosures with 2 drives inside, if you buy a modern one they can use up to 8TB drives, I like raid 1 because it has a copy of the data on both drives, if one drive fails you dont lose all your data, pop in a new drive and it will automatically recreate the raid (copy data off good drive to the new one), back in business. I have one of these, its esata or USB 3.0 interface... http://www.sansdigital.com/mobileraid/mr2utplusb.html

Comment: @Moab I'm not exactly sure OP is that technically experienced.

Comment: There is nothing technical at all about that enclosure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If money were no object, I'd consider LTO tape.  A tape drive will set up back several thousand dollars, and the tapes aren't cheap either, but the version 7 tapes will hold 6 TB each.  They are pretty much the gold standard for long term archival storage.

For a cheaper option, I would just use regular hard drives.  If you think you might fill up several drives, you could save money by buying regular desktop drives (the internal kind), and get a USB-to-ATA adapter to connect them with. Personally, I would skip the fancy external drives that come in molded plastic cases, but that's just my 2¢.

Comment: Really the accepted solution is to spend Several Thousand Dollars?

Answer (score 0):

There are many storage solutions available to you.

You could buy a NAS (Network Attached Storage) device [online](http://www.newegg.com/Network-Attached-Storage-NAS/Category/ID-241) for anywhere from $100 to $1000 without any configuration. You could also build a pretty good NAS device for less than $600.

If you need quick and easy access to your files (and are akin to losing things), get an internal drive or two, toss 'em in your case and forget about them.

You could also subscribe to a cloud storage platform like OneDrive or Google Drive. In my experience, external hard drives are very fragile, so the internal option is probably your best bet.

Good luck!

~ {firstName}

Comment: Google is charging 100$/month for 10TB, it's too much for my case but NAS seems like viable option, I'll research it. Thanks!

Comment: @DreadBoy that's usually for enterprise or business customers; I don't think their consumer plans go up that high.

Answer (score 0):

Original Poster said:

"•Buy another drive and use that one when first one is full. Rename each drive so you know which is which. Assign a drive letter to each that is farther down the alphabet, so that when you plug in a different drive the backups don't get "bumped" out of place.

Should I get external or internal one?
•Subscribe to some online backup service. I'm yet to find one that would offer just to save files without all cloud/sync stuff."

--Buy another USB drive. There are lots of reliable 2.5 inch external drives available. Internet chatter seems to mention 3.5 inch external drives as unreliable due to the external power supply required and flaky controllers.

The external drive would also be very helpful if you need to copy your videos to another computer.

**Avoid** the included software that comes with an external drive!! It is awful stuff and will make it horribly frustrating to recover and manage your files. Robocopy and SyncBack free are the gold standard for backups - they are fast and do not put your backups into some hard to read propriety archives.

Windows 8.1 and 10 "File History" is OK, but there is a learning curve.

--Online backup is fine for smaller files that you want to sync. OneDrive and Google Drive work well for small tasks.

--Don't try and upload many gigabytes up to some "cloud"!!! That would take a long time (days perhaps) to upload and would be costly. Plus, what if your internet connection goes down, or the cloud service bails out on you?

--A NAS would work, but they are not portable and can be overly complicated to manage.

Comment: If this is a commentary on my post, avoid posting it as another answer altogether. By the way, if you have the bandwidth, online backup is actually fairly viable. I can download 10GB in 5m; the same to upload in 3m